# Use entity_metadata_wrapper's field->getBundle on a multiple field

Tags: 7, entities

I have a multiple field on an entity, and would like to get the `$wrapped->field_profiles->getBundle()` property as an array from all the results, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, although I know it should be super obvious. My current non-wrapper-ish way of doing it is like the following code, but I'd prefer a clean one-liner. Is this possible? Thanks!

```
$wrapped = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $result);
array_map(function ($profile) {
  return $profile->type;
}, $wrapped->field_profiles->value());
```